# Which are the missing dates?

Tags: knowledge, number-sequence

Here are the dates for a series of events. As you can see, some of the dates are missing.
What are the missing dates. And what happened at these dates?

> $~~~????,~ 1914,~ ????,~ 1939,~ 1958,~ ????,~ 1978,~ 1978,~ 2005,~ 2013$

Comment: The event is the same for all of the dates.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=1978%2C+1978%2C+2005%2C+2013&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%221978%2C+1978%2C+2005%2C+2013%22) answers this nicely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These years - ???, 1914, ???, 1939, 1958, ???, 1978, 1978, 2005, 2013 - are the years of

> "Sede Vacante" (or: the starting years of new popes).

More precisely,

> **1903** Pius X
>  1914 Benedict XV
>  **1922** Pius XI
>  1939 Pius XII
>  1958 John XXIII
>  **1963** Paul VI
>  1978 John Paul I
>  1978 John Paul II
>  2005 Benedict XVI
>  2013 Francis

Answer (score 5):

The answer is

> **1899, 1915 and 1950**

All those years are

> the beginning years of all wars in 20th and 21st centuries involved by USA.
> Philippine-American War(1899-1902)
> World War I(1914-1918)
> Armenian Genocide(1915-1918)
> Word War II(1939-1945)
> The Korean War(1950)
> Vietnam War/Lebanon crisis(1958)
> Afghan War (1978)
> South Lebanon conflict(1978)
> Iraq Crisis(2005)
> Syrian Civil War(2013)

Comment: which started in 2013? how about 2005 and 1978?

Comment: Ok, good effort +1. But the dates are in chronological order. So no date after 1978 is missing, also a lot of wars would be missing if that was the trend.

Comment: So some criterion excludes the Gulf War and the war in Afghanistan.